# How to filter a GridView in Visual Basic WITHOUT any Database

Tags: vb.net, gridview, collections

I made a lot of research on internet, and have found a lot of tutorials about "how to filter/sort a GridView" in VB.NET, BUT, all of theme are using a Database.

In my case I only have these:

- MP3Song : a custom class with some property like "Title","Artist","Duration", etc.
- A List(Of MP3Song) : which is linked to my GridView like this:

`myMP3Collection = New List(Of MP3Song.MP3Song)`
`mp3SongBinndingSource.DataSource = myMP3Collection`

I'm using a `List(Of ...)` because when I populate this list, I do some verification and I'm likely to modify some "already added" data. And it is very easy for me :

`myMP3Collection.ElementAt(i).Extd = True 'Extd is a Boolean property, others are string...`

During my research I have seen that I should use a DataSet (easier to filter/sort a GridView).
Here is my question :

1. Should I make a `DataSet` based on my collection (populated by a `For Each` which scan my List, and add all item in `row` in my table
2. Or should I try to directly populate a `DataSet` instead of a `ListOf()`. If 2nd choice is better, is that easy as with collection to access and modify an element in a row ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your title asks how to filter without a database, your question is asking how to setup a DataSet.  Which one you want?

Comment: If DataSet is the best way, how to set it up and how to access to data in a specific row.

Comment: You could just use linq: `mp3SongBinndingSource.DataSource = myMP3Collection.Where(Function (x) x.Artist = "U2").ToList`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tim Van Wassenhove's [FilterList](https://timvw.be/2009/11/06/presenting-filterlist/) is just what you need. He extends the List(Of T) into SortableBindingLists and FilterLists.

While his code is C#, you can easily use an on-line converter. Or, create a C# .DLL, use the code, and reference that .DLL from your VB.NET app.

Comment: Thanks ! I was a bit tricky for me to properly import all C# library from Tim Van Wassenhove (FilterList and SortableBindingList) in VB.Net but it works !

What a easy way (I think) to filter my data !!! I just had to do like following in a `TextChanged` event :

`MP3FilterList.Filter(Function(MP3Song) MP3Song.Title.Contains(FilterTextBox.Text))`